# Combining "parallel arrays" into Dataframe structure

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I have the following data structure in json that I am trying to get into a dataframe using AWS Glue:

```
{
    "out": [
        {
            "attr": [ "a1", "a2", "a3" ],
            "val": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
            "text": "test1"
        },
        {
            "attr": [ "a4", "a5", "a6" ],
            "val": [ 4, 5, 6 ],
            "text": "test2"
        }
        
    ],
    "ids": [
        "id1",
        "id2"
    ]    
}
```

The "ids" field is a parallel array to the entries in "out".  I've been trying to get the following:

```
id     text     attr            val
--     ----     ----            ---
id1    test1    [a1, a2, a3]    [1,2,3]
id2    test2    [a4, a5, a6]    [4,5,6]
```

I've been able to split the ids and the content of "out" into two dataframes, but I cannot find a way to concatenate them horizontally.

Using

```
spark_context = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)
spark = glue_context.spark_session

print("Loading data...")
df = spark.read.json(<location>)
df.printSchema()
```

I get the following schema:

```
root
 |-- out: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- attr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- val: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the dataframe api,

```
df = spark.read.json('test.json', multiLine=True)

df.select(f.explode(f.arrays_zip('ids', 'out')).alias('data')) \
  .select('data.ids', 'data.out.*') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+---+------------+-----+---------+
|ids|attr        |text |val      |
+---+------------+-----+---------+
|id1|[a1, a2, a3]|test1|[1, 2, 3]|
|id2|[a4, a5, a6]|test2|[4, 5, 6]|
+---+------------+-----+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In my example I use spark SQL, but I am sure you can also pull it off with plain pyspark. The key idea is to use [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip) function. There's also the [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#zip_with) which you may want to have a look at.

```
import json

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

data = """
{
    "out": [
        {
            "attr": [ "a1", "a2", "a3" ],
            "val": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
            "text": "test1"
        },
        {
            "attr": [ "a4", "a5", "a6" ],
            "val": [ 4, 5, 6 ],
            "text": "test2"
        }
        
    ],
    "ids": [
        "id1",
        "id2"
    ]    
}
"""

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[json.loads(data)],
    schema="struct<out:array<struct<attr:array<string>,val:array<int>,text:string>>,ids:array<string>>")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("input")

spark.sql("""
SELECT
    zipped.ids as id, 
    zipped.out.*
FROM input 
    LATERAL VIEW explode(arrays_zip(out, ids)) _z as zipped
""").show(truncate=False)
```

returns:

```
+---+------------+---------+-----+
|id |attr        |val      |text |
+---+------------+---------+-----+
|id1|[a1, a2, a3]|[1, 2, 3]|test1|
|id2|[a4, a5, a6]|[4, 5, 6]|test2|
+---+------------+---------+-----+
```

Comment: You've taught me a new function: arrays_zip... that was exactly what I needed.